# What is the Microsoft equivalent to GCC option init_priority?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, static, linker

When compiling and linking a C++ library or program, there are no guarantees on the order of initialization of static C++ objects among translation units. [GCC offers `init_priority`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Attributes.html) to solve the problem for static archives, shared objects and programs:

> init_priority (priority)
>
> In Standard C++, objects defined at namespace scope are guaranteed to
>       be initialized in an order in strict accordance with that of their
>       definitions in a given translation unit. No guarantee is made for
>       initializations across translation units. However, GNU C++ allows
>       users to control the order of initialization of objects defined at
>       namespace scope with the init_priority attribute by specifying a
>       relative priority, a constant integral expression currently bounded
>       between 101 and 65535 inclusive. Lower numbers indicate a higher
>       priority.

(The static archive seems to be trickiest because it will (presumably) be linked by someone else).

What does Microsoft offer for controlling the order of initialization of static C++ objects among translation units?

Answer (score 4):

[`#pragma init_seg`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977wcck.aspx) is probably the most similar documented equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have not forgot about you. I just have not had time to test it (and accept if it works).